# Spring RabbitTemplate setRetryTemplate & setRecoveryCallback ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

**Question:** After a fixed amount of retries I would like to send the message to an error queue and consume it from its original queue. I want to find a generic solution because I handle a lot of different messages and depending on the exception they raise I want to act differently. How can I set the `RecoveryCallback` so that Spring triggers it after `maxRetries`?

**What I currently do**
I try to set a `RetryTemplate` and a `RecoveryCallback`.
When I run the application and publish a message to the `test` queue I expect the processing in `EListener#receive` to fail 3 times and then trigger my configured `RecoveryCallback` which then routes the message based on the context to a specific error queue.

**What actually happens**
What actually happens is that Spring Boot initializes the `RabbitAdmin` object with its own `RabbitTemplate` and therefore does not use my configured `RabbitTemplate` bean.

I have the following directory structure:

```
rabbit
  |___ EListener.java
  |___ Rabbit.java
test
  |___ Test.java
```

I have the following code in `Rabbit.java`

```
@Configuration
public class Rabbit {

    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(createRetryTemplate());
        rabbitTemplate.setRecoveryCallback(createRecoveryCallback());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    createRecoveryCallback() // Omitted for brevity
    createRetryTemplate() // Omitted for brevity
}
```

The `EListener.java` file contains:

```
@Component
public class EListener {

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "test", durable = "true"), exchange = @Exchange(value = "test", type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC, durable = "true", autoDelete = "true"), key = "test"))
    public void receive(Message m) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(m);
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

`Test.java` contains:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("rabbit")
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Test.class).application().run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `RetryTemplate` to the `RabbitTemplate` is to retry **publishing** messages.

To add retry on the consumer side, you have to add a retry interceptor to the listener [container's advice chain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#retry).

Since you are using `@RabbitListener`, the advice chain goes on the [listener container factory `@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven-enable), which means you'll have to declare one yourself instead of relying on the default one created by boot.

Stateless retry does the retries in-memory; statefull retry requeues the message; it requires a messageId property (or some other mechanism to uniquely identify messages).

Comment: Is it possible to just replace the `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` that is currently used as a default recoverer?

Comment: Unfortunately not; the recoverer is hard wired into [boot's config'd retry interceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java#L104). You could [wire up your own bean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java#L62) use boot's configurer, and then overwrite the `adviceChain` with your own interceptor.

Comment: Then I will do that. It would be great to have that in the first place. Thanks for the help.